# Which library does `Cmake` prefer to link to when invoking `target_link_libraries(target_name, library_name_without_postfix)`?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cmake, build, linker

Both static and shared versions of a specific library are in the same folder, then which library does `Cmake` prefer to link to when invoking `target_link_libraries(target_name, library_name_without_postfix)`?

Why?

Comment: That's up to your linker, but probably shared. If you put the name of a library file (rather than a CMake library target), CMake will just pass `-llibrary_name_without_postfix` on the linker line.

Comment: If nothing is specified, then the default is shared.

Comment: @Bhai Any reference?

Comment: @John https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html If both static and shared libraries are found, the linker gives preference to linking with the shared library unless the -static option is used.

Comment: @Bhai I see, thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If target_link_libraries takes the library name in the 2nd parameter, it entirely depends on the linker. In your case, the link line will be translated to

```
-llibrary_name_without_postfix.
```

In this case, it will be searched in the standard path like, LD_LIBRARY_PATH, /etc/ld.so.conf or in the system path.

Since you didn't say anything about the location, I assume the library lives in the current build directory. And you have a command somewhere including the current build directory in the linker path using `link_directories`. In this case, the default link is dynamic.

Comment: Thank you for your clarification. The aforementioned library is one of the targets which is **built together** with the binary program. It's strange that there is no `link_directories` in all `CMakeLists.txt` indeed, `target_link_libraries(binary_program_name, lib_name)` still could find the right path to the shared library.

Comment: @John Try to find the add_library command which builds the library. This should be something like `add_library(lib_name [optional STATIC or SHARED] list_of_files)`. If STATIC is not explicitly mentioned, then it's dynamic.

Comment: When you are passing a target name to `target_link_libraries`, CMake sets `link_directories` automatically.

Comment: @arrowd any reference to verify ? `link_directories` take a directory and `target_link_libraries` either take a name, or a target, or a link flag. None of these will translate well to a directory.

Comment: @Bhai Sorry, I couldn't show the project. It's not permitted.

Comment: @John Just check official documentation. `target_link_libraries` also accepts an absolute path to the library file, in which case also calls `link_directory` automatically. Same goes for target arguments - the path to the library can be extracted from them just fine.

Comment: @arrowd  "Same goes for target arguments - the path to the library can be extracted from them just fine. "    I don't fully understand you. For `  target_link_libraries(binary_program_name, lib_name), the aforementioned "lib_name"(e.g foo) is **not a path to a specific library**, it's a library **created** by the (almost) **same CMakeLists.txt** through `add_library(foo sources  headers)   `.

Comment: If you write `add_library(foo ...)`, you should use `target_link_libraries(program foo)`. CMake notes that `foo` is an existing library target and figure out the path to it.